# IDA api: get function argument definition

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

So let's say we have the following code:

```
0: lea rax, [rbp+8]
1: mov rcx, rax
2: mov rdx, 5
3: call my_fun
```

i want to get the actual argument of the my_fun call, which would be the `[rbp+8]` local var in this case.

I tried getting the addresses of the arguments with:

```
addrs = idaapi.get_arg_addrs(3)
```

but that returns the address of `mov rcx, rax`. From that i would need something like the use-definition chain on rax, which i couldn't find if supported by ida.

my ultimate goal is to cast all the arguments to my_fun calls to a specific type.
so here, i want to change the type of the local var [ebp+8] to another type

Comment: Do you want to use the Hex-Rays decompiler, or do you want to use IDA? The options are different for those two cases. Hex-Rays offers more options.

Comment: i have access to the hex-rays decompiler, i presume that would be the easier/more complete solution? Interested to also see a high level overview of how you would approach this with just ida, would that involve scripting something like a dataflow analysis module?